# How to view all the raw data that comes from a bluetooth device to your computer?

Tags: bluetooth, gamepad, gamepad-api

I have a gamepad with giroscope that works with Nintendo Switch, but there is no such feature for windows, but I think that the gamepad anyway send the information from giroscope but windows don't respond to it.

Comment: https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Bluetooth

Comment: what about soft for windows 10?

Comment: @ВасяПупкин How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If yes, you could Accept it as an Answer , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org). has a Windows and Linux version.
Capturing Bluetooth isn't that complex. see the Wireshark site for the [tutorial](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/wikis/CaptureSetup/Bluetooth).

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using the [WebHID API](https://web.dev/hid/). For your concrete question, maybe you can just directly use my [WebHID Nintendo Joy-Con driver](https://github.com/tomayac/joy-con-webhid) that makes gyroscope data available to the browser.